# Table Count in database

Tags: mysql, count, procedure

I want to get table count of my database. I have two queries and both queries giving different result. Can someone please tell me what is difference between these two queries ?
**1) SELECT count(*)  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES ;
2) show tables;**

I want to get total count of tables of my database. First I execute "Show tables;" and checked how much row it returns. Then I execute "SELECT count(*)  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES ;"  but this query giving more count than previous.

Comment: If you qualify the select to only look at my database then the result should be the same assuming you are USEing my database when you SHOW. eg SELECT count(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where table_schema = 'my database'

Comment: You should take the time to review https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-tables.html and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema.html and knowing the difference between views and tables may be pertinent.

Answer (score -1):

> SELECT count(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES ;

This query returns all the tables like user-created and system tables of the database.

> show tables;

This query returns only user-created tables from the database.

That's why first query returns more than count of second query.

Comment: This is absolutely incorrect answer.

Comment: @Shadow what makes you say that? show tables will show the tables from the USEd database and without qualification querying information_schema.tables will show tables from all databases.

Comment: @P.Salmon what you wrote is correct (although I would add that both statements list views as well, so if you want just tables, you need to filter the output), but this answer says something entirely different.